Multiple Mapped Network Drives Keep Changing
I have connected two HDD's and three USBs to a docking station which is connected to my Wi-Fi Hub. My hub only has one USB input which is taken up by the docking station. This arrangement results in five network locations called usb1, usb2, usb3, usb4 and usb5 which I mapped as Drive letters J,U,X,Y,Z.
After a day or so restarting my device and disconnecting from the network multiple times, several of the network locations switched meaning usb2 now links to the drive that was usb4 and vice versa meaning files are no longer where file explorer thought they were.
Is there any way to make it so the drive network locations refer to the same drive and don't change randomly.
Extra information:

BT Smart Hub 3
Universal Docking Station Kensington SD3600
Western Digital WD Blue WD10SPZX 1TB
Windows 11
One of the drives that switched was a USB stick and another was a HDD.
The USB drives are connected with USB 2
The HDD drives are connected with USB 3
I'm connected to my Hub via Wifi


Are the network paths themselves changing?

it sounds like the hub is dynamically mapping the disks to their names. if that is the case, no. What you already have should be sufficient as long as the disk for USB1 is always shared via samba using the name "USB1". but if the router decides that the name USB1 exposes the disk USB4, then there is nothing you can do on the windows side to fix that. perhaps there is a setting in the hub to fix that issue.

@music2myear I have updated my question to clear up the confusion. The path that used to link to the HDD now links to the USB stick and vice versa.

So this is going to be a router issue. You'll need some setting on your router that keeps the labels/assignments for each drive the same, and then use that as the mapping address. Maybe this means manually assigning a name to each drive on the router manually?

@music2myear I don't think this is possible on my router, is there another solution or do you know of a way to do it on my router and service provider BT?

It's not a service provider issue, unless and insofar as you are using a service-provider-provided router, in which case you should only use a modem from the provider, and get your own router which has the features you require, or, get a dedicated NAS device that can host the drives/storage you require.
